# Tool to convert .Glade (or xml) file to C source

Tags: c, windows, gtk, glade

I am looking for tool that can convert .Glade (or xml) file to C source.
I have tried g2c (Glade To C Translator) but i am looking for windows binary.

Any one does know any good tool for window.

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

glade2 works for me. though if you are using new glade3 features it won't help you..

Comment: can you provide link to glade2 download, i can't find it anywhere. there are just glade3 links. i am looking for glade2 for window.

Comment: try https://sourceforge.net/projects/gladewin32/files/
(sorry if it doesn't work, i'm using linux)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a tool. Just write a script in your favorite scripting language to format your glade file as a C string literal:

For example, let's call it `glade_file.c`:

```
const gchar *my_glade_file = 
    "<interface>"
        "<object class=\"GtkDialog\">"
            "<et-cetera />"
        "</object>"
    "</interface>";
```

Compile `glade_file.c` into your program, then do this when you build your interface:

```
extern const gchar *my_glade_file;
result = gtk_builder_add_from_string(builder, my_glade_file, -1, &error);
```

Comment: I want to see the generated code. I have created one very complex composite widget in glade, and if I start implementing it by manual coding it will take somuch time. so I am looking for a converter that will given me source for this widget which I have created in glade.

Comment: There is no generated code in Glade 3. If you already made the widget in Glade, why do you want to reimplement it manually??

Comment: because i want to create a list of it.

Comment: You can put the above code in the constructor of the widget, and then make a list of it...

Answer (score 2):

I had to write a little python script to do this, hope this helps others:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
class XmlWriter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.snippets = []
    def write(self, data):
        if data.isspace(): return
        self.snippets.append(data)
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self.snippets)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    writer = XmlWriter()
    xml = xml.dom.minidom.parse("example.glade")
    xml.writexml(writer)
    strippedXml = ("%s" % (writer)).replace('"', '\\"')

    byteCount = len(strippedXml)
    baseOffset=0
    stripSize=64

    output = open("example.h", 'w')
    output.write("static const char gladestring [] = \n{\n")
    while baseOffset < byteCount:
        skipTrailingQuote = 0
        if baseOffset+stripSize < byteCount and strippedXml[baseOffset+stripSize] == '"':
            skipTrailingQuote = 1
        output.write('  "%s"\n' % (strippedXml[baseOffset:baseOffset+stripSize+skipTrailingQuote]))
        baseOffset += stripSize + skipTrailingQuote

    output.write("};\n")
    output.close()
```