# how to use the glade xml file to make an executable program

Tags: c, xml, gtk, glade

I am learning to use glade 3 to create a GUI.

However, the *.glade file is an xml file. I am not sure how to go forward from here. Google search is not really helping. There is a question already asked for same thing here [Tool to convert .Glade (or xml) file to C source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787202/tool-to-convert-glade-or-xml-file-to-c-source) . However I am not really able to understand the answer given in that.

Can someone tell the basic flow of the development cycle using glade 3?

1. Design the UI in glade.
2. Generate the *.glade xml file.
3. AND THEN WHAT ????

How can the xml file be converted to an executable ?

A. Should I convert this xml file to a language (C) and compile the C code ?

B. Or is there a way for xml code to be directly converted to an ELF executable ?

I am trying to make the GUI for my own use. I use linux and want an ELF executable (like how I would get if I wrote the C code using gtk library and compiled it using gcc).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You asked this question 17 minutes ago as of writing this comment. Stack Overflow is a website; not everyone is looking at it at all hours, so you will need to be patient to get an answer. Anyway, glade files are just what the UI looks like. You need to write some code using the GTK+ toolkit to use the glade file. You can use C or any other language you like. The class you use to load the glade file into GTK+ 3 is GtkBuilder. (I don't know about GTK+ 2.) You can also use GResource, part of GLib, to embed the xml into your binary. Good luck!

Comment: @andlabls yea that was just a comment written out of frustration on all the unsuccesful googling and apparent lack of un-obscure howtos ... thanks for the pointers ..maybe i will look into GtkBuilder and GResource ... but for now i will just write the code myself ...will come back to glade later ...

Answer (score 0):

If we look at [the Wikipedia page for Glade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer) it has an entire section about how to use Glade in a program: with GtkBuilder. Now all that remains is to read [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html) and you can begin using Glade. No offense, but I've never used Glade before and this is fairly clear in all docs. For example, here's [Glade's homepage](https://glade.gnome.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
DerivedWindow::DerivedWindow()
{
  mainBox = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Box(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 7));
  builder = Gtk::Builder::create();
  try {
    builder->add_from_file("filename.glade");
  } catch (Glib::Error& ex) {
    errMsg("Window Builder Failed: " + ex.what());
  }

  Gtk::Box* box;
  builder->get_widget("name of box inside main window", box);
  if (!box) { this->destroy_(); return; }

  box->unparent();
  mainBox->pack_start(*box, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

  //optional - if you want full access to particular widgets
  builder->get_widget("name of widged id", widgetname);

  //connect signals here...

  add(*mainBox);
  show_all();
}
```

Note this is Gtkmm 3+.

It is important you unparent the box you got from the glade file, so you can attach it to your derived window.